# How to set Usage attribute using keytool

Tags: java, cryptography, keytool

When I look at the X509certificate class in java.security.cert, it has a methods such as `getExtendedKeyUsage()` and `getKeyUsage()`. Is there a way to set these values using the keytool?

Comment: Are you trying to change anything for a current certificate (which I was assuming) or is Bruno guessing correctly that you could also use this for new certs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new `-ext` option for [`keytool` in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#OptionsInAll). Check the table under the `-ext` documentation, in particular the `KU` and `EKU` options.

Note that you will usually be able to use a keystore produced/handled by Java 7's `keytool` with other versions of the JRE (including Java 6).

Of course, this will only work for certificate requests you generate (in which case the CA you use may choose to ignore or alter some of the content of your CSR) or certificates you issue (i.e. where you're the CA). You won't be able to change existing certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If there is, I've never seen it and I just checked with JDK (although highly unlikely). Note that key usage should be a signed attribute (as well as critical extension), so changing it generally won't work since it would break the signture of the issuing CA. It could be changed for a particular application (and the attribute stored separately, but that's not a function within Java key stores, and it won't be because it would be incompatible with the X509 standard.

Comment: "a signed attribute (a critical extension)". Signed attribute and critical extension are not the same thing. All attributes (and the entire content of an X.509 cert) are signed by the issuing CA. Whether an extension is critical or not is different: it's a way for the CA to tell the consumer of the cert that it must understand this particular extension.

Comment: @Bruno you are right of course, changed to &, was a bit sleepy at the time of posting - I was also assuming that the author was trying to change an existing certificate, I'll ask him

Answer (score 0):

The option appears to be keytool -ext EKU=codeSigning
But I haven't personally tried it yet.